# Refund for damaged luggage

Tags: refunds, easyjet, damaged-luggage

After a flight with Easyjet (EDR-MXP), my suitcase was damaged, but since I had to catch the last bus available (it was midnight), I did not file a complaint at the airport. Instead, I filed the damage refund request on their website, given that I had 7 days after the flight to do so. However, since I had to leave again in a few days, I had to buy another luggage at a shop in my city before they could reply. I bought a suitcase of the same brand and a similar model, that cost me 110 euros.

After some (a lot of) time, their insurance company handling the case (damagedluggage.com), replied offering me a new suitcase, priced around 65 euros on the manufacturer's site. I then replied asking if it was possible to have a refund of the new luggage instead, since I could not wait to have a new suitcase, nor to have mine repaired or even examined for a quote. I attached a picture of the old one, and the receipt of the new one.

Again, after some (a lot of) time, they replied asking for a proof of purchase of the old suitcase, or when I bought it and how much I paid. Of course I have not the original receipt, I bought my old one around 10 years ago, so I told them that I paid 110 euros, which was the price of the new one. Since it was the same brand and a similar model, I honestly believed that it was a fair answer. Furthermore, I just want to be refunded of what I paid now, I don't care how much I paid years ago, even if it cost me more.

Again, after some (a lot of) time, they replied me, and I quote:

> I would like to explain that easyJet has a limited liability and this is reflected in our settlement offers.
>   I note from your email that the value of the original luggage is 110€. It is our policy to deduct 50% where no receipt/proof of purchase is provided which is a common guideline with most airlines. We also can only offer a potential financial settlement against the damaged item, not new replacements.
>   But I have spoken with my manager and as a gesture of goodwill we can increase our offer to a 75% refund of 82.50€.
>   If you are in agreement with our offer please forward your account details so we can arrange a transfer of funds.

But:

1. They say that they cannot provide new replacements, while they did in the first email!
2. How can I provide a receipt for something that it's 10 years old?
3. Since they just trusted my word about the cost, why then pay less? I suppose they must prove me wrong.
4. There's no goodwill in the insurance world!

In my opinion, this stinks of good cop and bad cop. Is there anything true in what they say? I believe they're trying to discourage and wear me out, persuading me to accept less.
Furthermore, with this behaviour they are incouraging people to fraud insurances, inflating costs!

What should I do? Many thanks

Comment: It appears that your position is  "something ten years old was damaged, so you should pay the full price of a new one". No company, insurance or otherwise, will fall for that one.

Comment: They have offered you 82.50€ - I think that's fairly generous considering your luggage was 10 years old.  They started out offering new replacement for 65€ so 82.50€ is an improvement on that, plus you now have brand new luggage, not 10 years old.

Comment: Point 1 you misunderstand - EasyJet say they can only provide compensation on the basis of the damaged item, not *your* replacement for the damaged item. It stops people going out and buying very expensive "replacements" and demanding full recompense.

Comment: Point 2 many people keep receipts for many years, especially for items such as this where insurance claims may come up.  I'd suggest you start doing it - file your receipts away in a box.

Comment: Point 3 you got some use out of  it for 10 years, why should they pay the full amount?

Comment: €82.50 on a 10 year old suitcase sounds like a pretty good deal to me. I'd take it.

Comment: I just wanted to know if my rights were respected, not how much an old suitcase should be refunded. It's about procedures here, and I'm not pretending, I want to understand. Anyway, thanks for your replies.

Comment: We flew with EasyJet from Luton to Edinburgh in May 2022. On arrival, my new suitcase (1500 had been dropped (or thrown) from the plane – it had a huge dent in one corner, and one of its 4 wheels was completely missing. The agent at Edinburgh was very helpful, he took the details and told us how to apply for compensation. He was the only helpful person, unfortunately. Everybody else from this airline has been unhelpful and / or disbelieving my version of the experience. We submitted the correct forms in the correct manner; we supplied photographs of the ruined case. It is now February 2023 and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would, honestly, just forget about it.  You will never, ever win.  Even if you had reported it at the moment, all they do is **repair it for you**.

(Piece of tape.)

If it "can't" be repaired, they give you a **replacement**, which is the cheapest possible offbrand.

I always "hunt down every penny that is mine" and "never let anything go" but, it is absolutely certain, you will never, ever get anything out of them.

Just forget it - sadly.